# Is there any short hands for doing this logic?

Tags: php, shortcut

Here is the code....

```
if(!(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["sessionKey"]) && isset($_POST["page"]) && isset($_POST["ipp"]))){
        return;
}else{
   $email       = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);           
   $sessionKey  = htmlspecialchars($_POST["sessionKey"]);           
   $page        = htmlspecialchars($_POST["page"]);           
   $ipp         = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ipp"]);           
}
```

ok, the idea is I MUST assign the parameter with the same variables. For example, if I post a parameter "test" , I must assign this to a variable .... test... ...Is there any short cut for me to doing something like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data=array_map('htmlspecialchars',$_POST); 
extract($data);
```

Be careful with [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) this can override your existing variables with same name but you can change this behaviour by passing additional parameter to extract function.

Comment: What if $_POST contains an array? :-)

Comment: @Denis: That case is not listed in question. If that is, will update my answer accordingly

Comment: $_POST doesn't contain an array.  (How could it?)

Comment: @awm `<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="a"/> <input type="checkbox name="foo[]" value="b"/>`

Comment: Obviously, but your current code is both susceptible to issuing warnings if he uses it in a separate file that might have an array (see comment just above), and hugely prone to abuse (e.g. try posting is_logged_in=1 with your `extract($data)`).

Comment: If I wanna to make prefix before the variables it makes for me...for example, I would like to make pEmail, can I do this using the extract methods? thank you.

Comment: @Tattat: Yes, you can prefix variables with extract function `extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "p");`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en//function.extract.php

Also, `isset` accepts more than one parameter, so you could use it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["sessionKey"], $_POST["page"], $_POST["ipp"])) ...
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility for the extraction part:

```
foreach (array('email','sessionKey','page','ipp') as $v) {
  $$v = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$v]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon the `extract` answer, you can slice out only the $_POST entries that you need with:

```
$vars = array_intersect_key($_POST,
   array_flip(array("email", "sessionKey", "page", "ipp")));

// and then this replaces the isset() check and the extraction
if (count($vars) == 4) {
   extract(array_map("htmlspecialchars", $vars));
}
```